# Pushing new builds onto the development/testing device on iOS when meteor files change (meteor run ios-device)

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

I'm able to deploy my app for testing to the iPhone with `meteor run ios-device`.

But how do I get it to keep refreshing the build with the latest code I'm writing?

Even if I switch over to xCode and hit the run button again, it shows me an older version of the app. I'd like to avoid deleting/pushing the app again and again onto the device if I can help it.

To clarify again, the behavior I'd like is: **when I update the code in the meteorjs files, the meteor server refresh is triggered, this ought to refresh the app on my phone as well and display the new output**. This is how it works on the browser and I think android-cordova as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was making the mistake of deleting the app when I needed a new build from the Mac. This would delete the `Trust` that I was granting to my developer account to run apps on the iPhone. This would make XCode attempt to run the app on the device and error out.

So now I don't delete the app, and also I run `meteor run ios-device --verbose` (note the extra flag) to figure out any errors that are happening in the process.